# I try to install TweetDeck, but nothing happens

Tags: installation

Following the instruction from http://www.pablo-bloggt.de/linux/twitter-programm-fur-ubuntu-tweetdeck/, I go directly to http://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/.

But when I press the 'Download Now'-Button, it's Label changes to 'Tweetdeck wird installiert' but nothing else happens.

**Edit:**

I found [this](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20071500-264/adobe-scraps-air-for-linux-focuses-on-mobile/) which explains that I have to look for alternatives to Adobe Air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are unsure to install an unsupported Adobe software you can also run Tweetdeck from within the Chrome or Chromium browser by installing the application from [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl).

Another alternative for Ubuntu is [Qwit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quit).

Comment: I decided for the Chrome Webstore solution. Now it is running.

Answer (score 3):

TweetDeck depends on Adobe Air, Install it first and then go to website and install it!
http://get.adobe.com/air/
Unfortunately this is the message from Adobe:

**Adobe AIR for Linux is no longer supported. To access older, unsupported versions, please read the AIR archive.**

So If i have not missed something, then you better move to another tweeter client. If you do I suggest hotot